# search string in shell and print new line if not found

Tags: bash, shell

I have command with output:

```
Test TXT some Text1
Test TXT some Text2
Done TXT some Text3
Done TRT some Text1
Test TXT copy Text5
Done TXT some Text2
Test TRT many Text4
Test TRT some Text6
Done TXT many Text9
```

I want to search "TXT" and if found print the rest of the line. And if not found print a blank line like below:

```
some Text1
some Text2
some Text3

copy Text5
some Text2


many Text9
```

How to do this without using sed or awk?

Comment: Do you want the whole line or just `some Text1` part?

Comment: You write "*How to do this without using `sed`*" here, but below the answer by @Cyrus you write "*I cannot use awk, can we do this using sed only?*". Which is it? Do you want `sed` or something else?

Comment: Withoud `awk`or `sed` a solution can get trickier. Can you give more information like: Is the second field always 3 characters, can you tell which, do you have exactly 3 spaces in every line or are there more spaces allowed in the last field.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
if [[ "$line" == *TXT* ]]; then
    echo "$line"
else
    echo ""
fi
```

Or even shorter:

```
[[ "$line" == *TXT* ]] && echo "$line" || echo ""
```

Edit:  Yup, that'll do it.

```
$ while read line; do [[ "$line" == *TXT* ]] && echo "$line" || echo "" ; done <test.txt
Test TXT some Text1
Test TXT some Text2
Done TXT some Text3

Test TXT copy Text5
Done TXT some Text2


Done TXT many Text9
```

Comment: `< <(cat file)` is a useless use of cat. `<file` is enough

Comment: Fair criticism.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you write *"How to do this without using `sed`"*, but below the answer by @Cyrus you write *"I cannot use `awk`, can we do this using `sed` only?"*.

If it is a `sed` solution you want, you can simply use:

```
sed '/TXT/!s/^.*$//' file | sed '/TXT/s/^.*TXT[ ]//'
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your file as `file`, you get the following:

```
$ sed '/TXT/!s/^.*$//' file | sed '/TXT/s/^.*TXT[ ]//'
some Text1
some Text2
some Text3

copy Text5
some Text2


many Text9
```

**Explanation**

- `sed '/TXT/!s/^.*$//' file` find all lines *not* (e.g. `'!'`) containing `TXT` and simply makes them empty;
- piping to `sed '/TXT/s/^.*TXT[ ]//'` then finds all lines with `"TXT"` and trims from the beginning of the line through `"TXT "` (eliminating the `space` following `"TXT"`.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using perl and non-greedy regex (`.*?`) instead of sed or awk:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?(TXT |$)//' file
some Text1
some Text2
some Text3

copy Text5
some Text2


many Text9
```

It removes (replaces non-greedily with empty) to the end of `TXT` or the end of the line (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an absolutely awful answer.  I was surprised that it works.  I'm posting it here in the hope that someone might be able to tell me why it works.  The part I don't understand is why the blank lines show up - after all, the lines that don't have  a 'TXT ' separator don't match any patterns and should provide no output (or so I thought):

```
awk -F'TXT ' '{print $2}'
```

And here's the test:

```
awk -F'TXT' '{print $2}' <<EOF
> Test TXT some Text1
> Test TXT some Text2
> Done TXT some Text3
> Done TRT some Text1
> Test TXT copy Text5
> Done TXT some Text2
> Test TRT many Text4
> Test TRT some Text6
> Done TXT many Text9
> EOF
some Text1
some Text2
some Text3

copy Text5
some Text2


many Text9
```

Ooops.  Just saw that 'awk' and 'sed' are verbotten.

Here's  a modification to another's post that solves the problem.  I added a  little code to delete everything up to and including 'TXT ':

```
while 
  read line
do
[[ "$line" == *TXT* ]] && echo "${line#*TXT }" || echo ""
done
```

Please credit UtahJarhead with the correct answer on this one.  UtahJarhead's response just needed this construct "${line#*TXT }"  to delete the shortest prefix of line up to 'TXT '.